# Passing a list within methods in a class

Tags: python, html, class, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a problem with passing a variable from a method to method within a given class.

The code is this (I am practicing beginner):

```
class Calendar():
    def __init__(self,link):
        self.link = link
        self.request = requests.get(link)
        self.request.encoding='UTF-8'
        self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.request.text,'lxml')

    def DaysMonth(self):
        Dates = []
        tds = self.soup.findAll('td',  {'class':'action'})
        for td in tds:
            check = (td.findAll('a')[0].text)
            if "Víkendová odstávka" in check:
                date = td.findAll('span')[0].text
                Dates.append(date)
        return Dates

    def PrintCal(self):
        return ['Víkendová odstávka serverů nastane ' + date + '. den v měsíci.' for date in Dates]

    def main(self):
        PrintCal(DaysMonth())
```

I would like to pass the list Dates from the method DaysMonth to the method PrintCal. When I initiate the class, i.e. cal = Calendar('link'), and run cal.PrinCal(), I get that the name Dates has not been defined. If I run cal.DaysMonth(), the output is as expected.

What is the issue here? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dates` is a local variable in the `DaysMonth` method, and is therefore not visible anywhere else. Fortunately, `DaysMonth` does return `Dates`, so it's easy to get the value you want. Simply add the following line to your `PrintCal` method (before the `return` statement):

```
Dates = self.DaysMonth()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do too much in the Calendar object, particularly in the **init** method. You don't want to combine the scraping and parsing of a website at the time the object is instantiated. I would use the Calendar object to store and display the results of the scraping/parsing. If you need everything to be object-oriented, than create a separate Scraper/Parser class that handles that part of the logic.

```
class Calendar():
    def __init__(self, dates):
        self.dates = dates

    def display_dates(self):
        return ['Víkendová odstávka serverů nastane ' + date + '. den v měsíci.' 
                   for date in self.dates]


r = requests.get(link, encoding='UTF-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,'lxml')
dates = []
for td in soup.findAll('td',  {'class':'action'}):
    check = (td.findAll('a')[0].text)
    if "Víkendová odstávka" in check:
        dates.append(td.findAll('span')[0].text)

c = Calendar(dates=dates)
print(c.display_dates)
```